# Jest stops with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" although I've set transformIgnorePatterns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm running `npm run test`, which runs `jest`, but a test suite fails with the following message:

```
/home/anthony/nosync/development/openmeteo/enhydris-web-frontend/node_modules/vue-notifications/dist/vue-notifications.js:130
export default VueNotifications;

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Here is the related configuration in `jest.config.js`:

```
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(vue-notifications)/)'],
```

I also run `npm run test -- --clearCache` frequently just to be sure. But `transformIgnorePatterns` doesn't seem to be having any effect.

The first line of the error message, as you can see, ends in `:130`. What is this number? Is it the line number where the error occurs? Actually the line `export default VueNotifications` is line 117. If I add some empty lines to move it down, I still get `:130`. (If I comment it out the problem goes away, although of course the tests still fail because the export is needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [known Jest bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10256)—transformIgnorePatterns doesn't work with `.babelrc`, only with `babel.config.js`. I converted my `.babelrc` to `.babel.config.js` and it's working now.